# Creating a blank opengl texture

Tags: opengl, textures

I'm working on a game engine, and one of the functions in the Texture class should be to create a blank texture with a specified width, height, and pixel format.

I know how to create the texture and all that, I also know that I can format it using glTexImage2d with null as the data. What annoys me though is that I have to tell openGL the format of my data (even though it's null) which would mean I have to write a function which converts the PIXEL_INTERNAL_FORMAT enum into a PIXEL_FORMAT and a PIXEL_TYPE.

How can I get opengl to allocate memory only based on the PIXEL_INTERNAL_FORMAT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PIXEL_FORMAT` and `PIXEL_TYPE` aren't supposed to match `PIXEL_INTERNAL_FORMAT`.  They're supposed to describe the data you pass in, so OpenGL can convert it if necessary.  When no data is passed in, there will be no conversion.

So you can use any legal values for these two parameters, when the data pointer is null (assuming you do not have a VBO bound).

Comment: That is what I thought too. But if I create a texture using DEPTH_COMPONENT as the PIXEL_INTERNAL_FORMAT, OpenGL gives me an INVALID_OPERATION error if I use anything other than DEPTH_COMPONENT as PIXEL_FORMAT.

Comment: @Hannesh: You're right: "GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if internalFormat is GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, or GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32, and format is not GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT."  But there are a very small number of these special cases.